# Incompatible PrimeFaces 6.1 and AdminLTE Template

Tags: jquery, jsf, primefaces, frontend

I'm having a JavaEE project where the front end is being used the open source AdminLTE template along with PrimeFaces 6.1 components.

We removed the jQuery import that the AdminLTE template used and left only the jQuery of PrimeFaces, so we did not have conflict problems.

**We have the following problem:** in a PanelGrid component of primefaces we add a Tab component. When you click a Tab with a SelectOneMenu component that is being loaded directly from a database, we receive the following error message when we inspect the page through Browser.

Error:

[image]

If the `SelectOneMenu` component is loaded with values ​​from an enum this error does not occur. I was unable to identify jQuery incompatibility.

The error occurs in the component of `id = selectTipEndID` inside the `TAB` component named `Addresses`.

Page error:

[image]

Imports of AdminLTE into our template:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"  
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    xmlns:jsf="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf"
    xmlns:sgr="http://www.sgr.com.br/jsf">

<h:head>
    <title>Web</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"/>
    <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no" name="viewport"/>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"/>

    <!-- Declarações CSSS -->
    <h:outputStylesheet library="bootstrap" name="css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
    <h:outputStylesheet library="dist"      name="css/AdminLTE.min.css"/>
    <h:outputStylesheet library="dist"      name="css/skins/_all-skins.min.css"/>

    <ui:insert name="css"/>

    <!-- Declarações JavaScript -->
    <h:outputScript library="bootstrap"     name="js/bootstrap.min.js"/>
    <h:outputScript library="dist"          name="js/app.js"/>
    <h:outputScript library="primefaces"    name="jquery/jquery.js"/>
    <h:outputScript library="primefaces"    name="jquery/jquery-plugins.js"/>
    <h:outputScript library="primefaces"    name="primefaces-locale.js"/>

    <ui:insert name="javaScript"/>

</h:head>

</html>
```

Page where the problem occurs:

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
                xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
                xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
                xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"  
                xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
                xmlns:o="http://omnifaces.org/ui"
                xmlns:jsf="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf"
                xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
                xmlns:sgr="http://www.sgr.com.br/jsf"  
                template="/WEB-INF/facelets/templates/layout.xhtml">

    <ui:param name="form_id" value="formCadFuncionario"/>
    <ui:param name="titlePage" value="Funcionario"/>
    <ui:param name="subTitlePage" value="Cadastrado de Funcionarios"/>
    <ui:param name="funcionarioBean" value="#{funcionarioBean}"/>

    <ui:define name="panelCadastro">
        <p:tabView>
            <p:tab title="Dados Gerais">
                <p:panelGrid columns="2" layout="grid" columnClasses="ui-grid-col-2, ui-grid-col-7" styleClass="ui-panelgrid-blank">
                    <p:outputLabel value="Nome:"/>
                    <p:inputText id="inptNome" value="#{funcionarioBean.funcionario.nome}">
                        <sgr:upperCase/>
                    </p:inputText>
                </p:panelGrid>

                <p:panelGrid columns="2" layout="grid" columnClasses="ui-grid-col-2, ui-grid-col-5" styleClass="ui-panelgrid-blank">
                    <p:outputLabel value="Tipo Pessoa:"/>
                    <p:selectOneMenu id="selIDectTipPes" value="#{funcionarioBean.funcionario.tipoPessoa}" converter="tipoPessoaConverter" disabled="true">
                        <p:ajax event="change" update="lblCpfID"/>
                        <f:selectItems value="#{funcionarioBean.funcionario.tiposPessoa}"/>
                    </p:selectOneMenu>

                    <p:outputLabel id="lblCpfID" value="#{funcionarioBean.funcionario.tipoPessoa eq 'FISICA' ? 'CPF' : 'CNPJ'}:"/>
                    <p:inputText id="iptCpfID" value="#{funcionarioBean.funcionario.cpfCnpj}" maxlength="14">
                        <sgr:onlyNumber/>
                    </p:inputText>

                    <p:outputLabel value="Nascimento:"/>
                    <p:inputMask id="dataNascID" value="#{funcionarioBean.dataNascimento}" mask="99/99/9999"/>

                    <p:outputLabel value="Cargo:"/>
                    <p:selectOneMenu id="selctCarID" value="#{funcionarioBean.funcionario.cargo}" converter="cargoConverter">
                        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Selecione" itemValue=""/>
                        <f:selectItems value="#{funcionarioBean.listaCargos}"/>
                    </p:selectOneMenu>
                </p:panelGrid>
            </p:tab>            

            <p:tab title="Endereços">
                <p:panelGrid id="pnlEnderecoID" columns="2" layout="grid" columnClasses="ui-grid-col-2, ui-grid-col-5" styleClass="ui-panelgrid-blank">
                    <p:outputLabel value="Tipo Endereço:"/>

                    <!-- ::::::::::: Error Here :::::::::::-->
                    <p:selectOneMenu id="selectTipEndID" value="#{funcionarioBean.endereco.tipoEndereco}" converter="tipoEnderecoConverter">
                        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Selecione" itemValue=""/>
                        <f:selectItems value="#{funcionarioBean.listaTiposEndereco}" var="obj" itemLabel="#{obj.descricao}" itemValue="#{obj}"/>
                    </p:selectOneMenu>

                    <p:outputLabel value="Cep:"/>
                    <p:inputText id="iptCepID" value="#{funcionarioBean.endereco.cep}">
                        <sgr:onlyNumber/>
                    </p:inputText>

                    <p:outputLabel value="logradouro:"/>
                    <p:inputText id="iptLograID" value="#{funcionarioBean.endereco.logradouro}">
                        <sgr:upperCase/>
                    </p:inputText>

                    <p:outputLabel value="Número:"/>
                    <p:inputText id="iptNum" value="#{funcionarioBean.endereco.numero}">
                        <sgr:onlyNumber/>
                    </p:inputText>

                    <p:outputLabel value="Complemento:"/>
                    <p:inputText id="iptComplID" value="#{funcionarioBean.endereco.complemento}">
                        <sgr:upperCase/>
                    </p:inputText>

                    <p:outputLabel value="Referência:"/>
                    <p:inputText id="iptRefeID" value="#{funcionarioBean.endereco.referencia}">
                        <sgr:upperCase/>
                    </p:inputText>
                </p:panelGrid>

            </p:tab>
        </p:tabView>
    </ui:define>

</ui:composition>
```